# Xamarin Sqlite-pcl-net Maximum value of a column

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, sqlite-net-pcl

I am using latest version of  Sqlite-net-pcl Nuget by Frank A. Krueger .

I need to get the maximum value of the column AccountNumber from the table AccountMasterModel.

I tried this

```
 public Task<List<int>> GetAccountMaxAsync()
        {
                return database.QueryAsync<int>("SELECT Max(AccountNumber) FROM [AccountMasterModel] ");
        }
```

I call this kmethod as follows

```
List<int> max = new List<int>();
 max = await App.Database.GetAccountMaxAsync();
```

The code executes successfully for me. Even I have the values 23 and 54  in the AccountNumber Column I always get the value 0 in max. Actually I need to 54 in max but I get only 0. Need a help here.

Answer (score 4):

```
var max = await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT Max(AccountNumber) FROM [AccountMasterModel] ", null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed the query as shown and I got the result .    `("select * from [AccountMasterModel] where [AccountNumber]=(select max([AccountNumber]) from [AccountMasterModel]) ")`